# Setup Shiro for non-mounted pages

Tags: wicket, shiro

On my current project, I use wicket and Shiro for authentication and authorisation. The problem is that for pages with an error code 404 the session is lost. Only mounted pages i.e. pages with a fixed path (/home, /users...) get a session, so when I type server:port/giberish the session is lost and I see the login page in the header. It seems that this behaviour is implicit because I could not find anywhere configuration for this.